# How can I access the current fragment transaction in Fragment.onPause() in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

My fragment needs to differentiate whether it will be replaced or removed in its onPause() method. Either if I started a new transaction replacing/removing it or if the user is going back in the backstack. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: "My fragment needs to differentiate whether it will be replaced or removed in its onPause() method" -- why? What happens with configuration changes, or anything else that affects your fragments?

Comment: Because it should affect the state of its activity when it's gone. (The view which held the fragment changes its look)